# QML отрезать от Rectangle

Tags: qt, qml

Есть Rectangle от которого я хочу отрезать угол:
[image: Rectangle на белом фоне] 
[image: отрезанный]

Rectangle заполняет все Window, который является прозрачным(применил Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window)
Мой код:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    color: "transparent";
    id: w1;
    Rectangle {
        color: "green";
        anchors.fill: parent;
    }
}
```

Какие есть идеи?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ниже одно из возможных решений:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    width: 300
    height: 300
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Window
    color: "transparent";
    id: w1;

    Rectangle{
        color: "green";
        anchors.fill: parent;
        Rectangle {
            width: 120
            height: 120

            x: parent.width - width / 2
            y: - height / 2
            color: "white"

            radius: 100
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. картинка получается максимально похожей на желаемый результат. При необходимости можно поиграть со значением y: x: чтобы спозиционировать центр белого Rectangle